# Usage of NetGroupGetUsers

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I want to get users of a group using `NetGroupGetUsers` function.

```
DWORD dwError = 0;
NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
LPDWORD entriesread=0;
LPDWORD totalentries=0;
LPBYTE *buff;
nStatus=NetGroupGetUsers(NULL,L"Users",0,buff,MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                          entriesread,totalentries,NULL);
```

When i use this i get this error;

```
xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xffffffffffffffff.
```

And how can i read buff when it works? And also i tried this;

```
GROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *buff;
nStatus=NetGroupGetUsers(NULL,L"Users",0,(LPBYTE*)&buff,MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
entriesread,totalentries,NULL);
```

but same error occurred.

EDIT: nStatus value is `NERR_GroupNotFound` i think the reason of the access violation is trying to read buff which isn't actually set.

EDIT 2: i used this function `NetLocalGroupGetMembers`. now it gives success but the `buff->grui0_name` is meaningless. there is a user named "ali" but the value of the `buff->grui0_name` is just "d". WHAT AM I DOING WRONG?

The Last Code;

```
LPCWSTR TargetGroup = L"group1";

DWORD dwError = 0;
NET_API_STATUS stat;

GROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *buff;
LPDWORD entriesread=new DWORD;
LPDWORD totalentries=new DWORD;

stat=NetGroupGetUsers(NULL,TargetGroup,0,(LPBYTE *)&buff,MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,
                          entriesread,totalentries,NULL);
```

for EDIT 2;

```
stat=NetLocalGroupGetMembers(NULL,TargetGroup,0,(LPBYTE *)&buff,
                  MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,entriesread,totalentries,NULL);
```

Please help...

Comment: I suspect you need to pass non-null values for entriesread and totalentries.

Comment: i tried like this; LPDWORD entriesread=new DWORD; is it true? it still doesn't work.

Comment: @isokorum You're probably better off with `DWORD entriesread=0, totalentries=0; NetGroupGetUsers(..., &entriesread, &totalentries, ...);`

Comment: yeah thanks its worked in two ways too. i figured out my problem. i controlled    nStatus variable it is     NERR_GroupNotFound. Now i am getting crazy with this. i also add a new group as group1 and add one user. but it couldn't find the group again.i don't know what to do.

Comment: i mean the reason of access violation is the buff isn't have anything.

Comment: Please show us your new code.

Comment: You're passing level 0 to NetLocalGroupGetMembers, so you're getting an array of SID structures, not an array of strings.  Pass level 1 and make buff a pointer to LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_1.

Comment: Wow i am such an idiot. its Worked. Thanks a lot. Thanks to everybody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LPCWSTR TargetGroup = L"group1";

NET_API_STATUS stat;

LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_1 *buff;
LPDWORD entriesread=new DWORD;
LPDWORD totalentries=new DWORD;

stat=NetLocalGroupGetMembers(NULL,TargetGroup,1,(LPBYTE *)&buff,
                        MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,entriesread,totalentries,NULL);



wprintf(buff->lgrmi1_name);
```

This code is working great now. Thanks to everybody.

Comment: This code should not be copied, because it leaks and the `new DWORD` is not neccessary. I will add a fixed version as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any memory for `buff`. You should be writing

```
GROUP_USERS_INFO_0 *buff;
... NetGroupGetUsers(..., (LPBYTE*)&buff, ...);
```

otherwise you're telling NetGroupGetUsers to write the results to a garbage location. Note that the `bufptr` parameter is documented as `[out]`. That means that it is the caller's responsibility to specify where the result should go. [There's more to calling a function than just getting the types to match](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/12/28/508689.aspx).

I'm surprised you didn't get an "use of initialized variable" warning from the compiler.

Comment: Yeah i tried this too. Now there is no access violation but status `NetGroupGetUsers` function returned is `NERR_GroupNotFound`. Thanks. i think i should edit it.

Comment: And in the MSDN reference says "The system allocates the memory for this buffer".

Comment: Right, the system allocates the memory, and it uses the `bufptr` parameter to tell you where that memory is. You in turn have to allocate memory to hold that pointer, so that you can receive the answer. That's why it's a pointer to a pointer. (Remember, in C, all parameters are passed by value, not reference.)

Comment: Yes thanks and Sorry i am trying to solve this meaningless problem for hours so i am tired.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the version without new:

```
LPCWSTR TargetGroup = L"group1";

NET_API_STATUS stat;

LOCALGROUP_MEMBERS_INFO_1 *buff;
DWORD entriesread;
DWORD totalentries;

stat = NetLocalGroupGetMembers(NULL,TargetGroup,1,(LPBYTE *)&buff,
    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH,&entriesread,&totalentries,NULL);

wprintf(buff->lgrmi1_name);
```