# NetGroupGetUsers only ever returns NERR_GroupNotFound (2220)

Tags: windows, winapi, netapi32

[I am](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72180007/12597) trying to call the Winapi function [**NetGroupGetUsers**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmaccess/nf-lmaccess-netgroupgetusers):

> The NetGroupGetUsers function retrieves a list of the members in a particular global group in the security database, which is the security accounts manager (SAM) database or, in the case of domain controllers, the Active Directory.

I've tried calling the function with every variation of `serverName` and `groupName` i can think of:

| ServerName | GroupName | Error code | Description |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| null | docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| null | OBSIDIAN\docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| null | .\docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| OBSIDIAN | docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| OBSIDIAN | OBSIDIAN\docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| OBSIDIAN | .\docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| . | docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| . | OBSIDIAN\docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |
| . | .\docker-users | 2220 | The group name could not be found |

Where the error code `2220` corresponds to the constant:

- **`NERR_GroupNotFound`**: The global group name in the structure pointed to by **bufptr** parameter could not be found.

## Long Version

There is a group on my local workstation called `docker-users`:

```
>whoami /groups

GROUP INFORMATION
-----------------

Group Name            Type  SID                                           Attributes
===================== ===== ============================================= ==================================================
OBSIDIAN\docker-users Alias S-1-5-21-502352433-3072756349-3142140079-1006 Mandatory group, Enabled by default, Enabled group
```

And you can see the group members in `netplwiz`:

[image]

You can also see the group members in the [**Local Users and Groups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/access-control/local-accounts) MMC snap-in.

1. Starting with the SID (e.g. `S-1-5-21-502352433-3072756349-3142140079-1006`)
2. Then call [**LookupAccountSID**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsida) to have it return:

   - <kbd>DomainName</kbd>
   - <kbd>AccountName</kbd>
   - <kbd>SID type</kbd>
3. If the **SidType** represents a group (i.e. <kbd>SidTypeAlias</kbd>, <kbd>SidTypeWellKnownGroup</kbd>, or <kbd>SidTypeGroup</kbd> - [which all mean "group"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39380857/12597))

We want the group members. So we call **NetGroupGetUsers**:

> `NetGroupGetUsers(null, "`<kbd>DomainName</kbd>`\`<kbd>AccountName</kbd>`", 1, out buffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, out entriesRead, out totalEntries, null);`

Except it fails. Every time. No matter what.

### The question

Why does the call fail?

What is the correct way to specify:

- Server name
- group name

Of course, for all i know it could be an ABI alignment issue. The only way to find out is if someone else tries calling the function on their local (domain joined or non-domain joined PC - doesn't matter).

### [CRME for the lazy](https://www.reddit.com/r/funny/comments/36q7qm/link_for_the_lazy/)

```
program GetGroupUsersDemo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Windows;

function NetGroupGetUsers(servername: LPCWSTR; groupname: LPCWSTR; level: DWORD;
        out bufptr: Pointer; prefmaxlen: DWORD; out entriesread: DWORD;
        out totalentries: DWORD; ResumeHandle: PDWORD): DWORD; stdcall; external 'netapi32.dll';

function GetGroupMembers(ServerName, GroupName: UnicodeString): HRESULT;
var
    res: DWORD; {NET_API_STATUS}
    buf: Pointer;
    entriesRead: DWORD;
    totalEntries: DWORD;
    i: Integer;
    server: PWideChar;
const
    MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH = Cardinal(-1);
begin
    server := PWideChar(ServerName);
    if server = '' then
        server := nil;

    res := NetGroupGetUsers(server, PWideChar(GroupName), 1,
            {var}buf,
            MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, //Let the function allocate everything for us
            {var}entriesRead,
            {var}totalEntries,
            nil);
    Result := HResultFromWin32(res);
end;

procedure Test(ServerName, GroupName: UnicodeString);
var
    hr: HRESULT;
    s: string;
begin
    hr := GetGroupMembers(ServerName, GroupName);

    s := ServerName;
    if s = '' then
        s := 'null'; //can't have people not reading the question

    Writeln('| '+s+' | '+GroupName+' | '+IntToStr(hr and $0000FFFF)+' | '+SysErrorMessage(hr)+' |');
end;

procedure Main;
begin
    Writeln('| ServerName | GroupName | Error code | Description |');
    Writeln('|------------|-----------|------------|-------------|');

    Test('', 'OBSIDIAN\docker-users');
    Test('', '.\docker-users');

    Test('OBSIDIAN', 'docker-users');
    Test('OBSIDIAN', 'OBSIDIAN\docker-users');
    Test('OBSIDIAN', '.\docker-users');

    Test('.', 'docker-users');
    Test('.', 'OBSIDIAN\docker-users');
    Test('.', '.\docker-users');
end;

begin
  try
     Main;
        Readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

### Bonus Reading

- [How to get members of a Windows (security) group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72180007/how-to-get-members-of-a-windows-security-group?noredirect=1#comment127531738_72180007)
- [Usage of NetGroupGetUsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7978227/usage-of-netgroupgetusers)
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21985159/Group-not-found-error-on-NetGroupGetUsers.html
- https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/11273935/NetGroupGetUsers-API.html
- https://microsoft.public.vb.winapi.networks.narkive.com/ssfpNHJR/problem-with-local-groups
- https://forum.powerbasic.com/forum/user-to-user-discussions/powerbasic-for-windows/5791-newbeeeeee-help-please

Comment: Have you debugged netplwiz to see if it actually uses that function?

Comment: I have not debugged netplwiz. But i have spent the last few hours scouring the Windows source code for clues on what the parameters to **NetGroupGetUsers** are.

Comment: Your screenshot is from a mmc snap-in and not netplwiz?

Comment: Netplwiz. What do you get when you call the API?

Comment: I did not call anything, after wasting time looking at Netplwiz only to discover that the dialog from your screenshot lives somewhere else I had already wasted enough time and moved on. lusers.msc or something along those lines and then you can debug mmc.exe

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have easy access to a domain-joined machine at the moment, but you can enumerate groups with NetGroupEnum() to see what format NetGroupGetUsers() would expect. As someone in the other thread suggested, there is also NetLocalGroupEnum(). It's been a long time since I've used these APIs and I don't recall what the distinction is between a 'group' and a 'local group', so perhaps that's part of the issue as well.

Comment: @Luke My first attempt is to call `NetGroupGetUsers` with a `local` group - no domain joined machine needed. If i can ever get that to work, i'll move on to trying to call `NetGroupGetUsers` with the name of a domain group.

Comment: because *docker-users* not a group. this is alias. so you and must got error `NERR_GroupNotFound` . you must call `NetLocalGroupGetMembers` on alias.

Comment: also you need use *'docker-users'* but not *'OBSIDIAN\docker-users'*

Comment: @RbMm Without specifying the *"Domain"*, how does the function know if it is a *"local"* group or a *"domain"* group? Also: i did try just `docker-users`. (see above)

Comment: function dont know are this group or alias. `NetGroupGetUsers` work only with groups. `NetLocalGroupGetMembers` work only with aliases. need pass only group/alias name without domain name. this api enumerate domains in SAM db by self and search in every domain

Comment: if you want use Net api - https://pastebin.com/nKykti9i . if want max power and perfomance - direct use Sam api (internally Net api of course call this ) https://pastebin.com/peWkZi5i

Comment: With [this code](https://pastebin.com/b4q03JmB) on my non-domain machine I get [this output](https://pastebin.com/w1NUe5mg).